# How do I turn an infinite series into a function in the form y=f(x)?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, functions, numerical-calculus

I am trying to determine the area between the curves defined by $\sum^{n}_{k=1} \frac {1}{k}$ and $y=\ln n$, which don't intersect. How can I turn the series $\sum^{n}_{k=1} \frac {1}{k}$ into a function in the form $y=f(x)$ so I can apply the Newton-Coates formulae (the Trapezoidal rule)?

Comment: Do you mean how to find a function $f(x)$ such that $f(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$?

Comment: Yes, I suppose that is what I'm asking for. I'm trying to turn the infinite series into a function that can be integrated normally

Comment: What about replacing $n$ by $\lfloor x\rfloor$? That would mean, you get a step function.

Comment: So then I can get rid of the summation $\sum$ and just add floor function to x? so my function would become $y = \frac{1}{\floor{x}}$?

Comment: I mean $f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor x\rfloor}\frac{1}{k}$.

Comment: Ah, okay. I'm not too familiar with this... Can I integrate it?

Comment: I think you want to use the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) or the closely related [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number)..